# rails - help setting up models - has_one - belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations

I've quite a simple query regarding models.

I have a model -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :interest
end
```

And another -

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donor
end
```

My Interest table is prepolated with interests - "football", "swimming", "tennis"
Each user can only have one interest, but an interest can have many users.

My set up at the moment seems to allow an interest to only have one user.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `has_many` on `Interest` and `belongs_to` on `User`. Remember about Rails convention in naming things:

```
belongs_to :interest
```

..and...

```
has_many :users
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. It's still not working. Do I need to set up a migration?

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to add column to `User` named `:interest_id`, and remove unused column `:user_id` from `iterests` table.